# Get a number from a String using sed and regular expression

Tags: regex, sed

I have a string:

```
abc = "2342"
```

or:  any string = "any number"

I wanna have a return value of 2342 (or any number)

How can I do it (using SED would be the best)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/^[^=]*= *"\([^"]*\)"$/\1/'
```

or

```
sed -E 's/^[^=]*= *"([^"]*)"$/\1/'
```

Assumptions:

- Any non-'=' can appear to the left of the '='
- Any character (not just digits) can appear between the '"'s
- Only ' 's between the '=' and the first '"'
- No characters after the second '"'